Temporary failure in name resolution runing Ubuntu 22.04
This error appears for machines on my local network but not on any other site, e.g. google.com.
This started after the machine in question was used to test a local 10. network.  The gnome network configure tool did not fix the problem. A web search has many sites addressing this problem all pointing to either a netmanagement conf problem or a resolv.conf issue.
Using the the net management tool did not fix the issue and the resolv.conf file was correct.

Issue resolved. This problem was in the /etc/nsswitch.conf file ... when using this machine for testing with a fixed ip on a 10 dot network the line:
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
was comment out and the line "hosts:          files dns" was added ... these were NOT correct when reconfiguring the network for dhcp service on my                                                                    router ... uncommenting the "files mdsn..." line and removing "hosts: files dns" line fixed the problem ...
I am posting this largely because none of the online answers to this problem even mention the /etc/nsswitch.conf file nor do the network "tools" fix this file ...
